# Can litjs be used to handle multiple tools on one Node server?

Tags: node.js, express, lti

The litjs library makes it easy to create a tool using the LTI protocol.
Is it possible to create multiple tool providers on one node instance using ltijs?
All of the examples make it look like a only one tool per server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the easiest way to do this would be to have multiple subdomains, one for each tool. Something like this:

```
import * as subdomain from 'express-subdomain';
const lti = require('ltijs').Provider    
// set up lti but don't call lti.deploy()
app.use(subdomain('lti1.myapp.com'), lti.app);
```